# Please tell me what's wrong with my strtok function

Tags: c, split, c-strings, strtok, function-definition

I created the strtok function as below.
However, although I didn't get an error, it didn't work.
Please tell me where the problem is.
I'm sorry if this sentence is hard to read.

```
#include <stddef.h> // NULL
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc
#include <string.h> // strncpy

char* my_strtok(char *src, const char *delims) {

static char* nextgettok;
char *nxt;//トークンの先頭アドレス
char *dlm;//トークンの区切アドレス

if(*delims){
  nextgettok = src;
}else{
  src =nextgettok;
}

nxt = NULL;
while(*src)
{
  if(nxt == NULL)
  {
    if(strchr(src,*delims) == NULL)nxt = src;
  }else
  {
        if(strchr(src,*delims) != NULL)
        {
          dlm = src;
          *dlm = '\0';
          nextgettok = dlm + 1;
          break;
        }
   }
   src++;
}
  return nxt;

}
```

Comment: The first `if` statement should be `if(src != NULL)`

Comment: @user3386109 Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Merrifield This code snippet if(*delims){
  nextgettok = src;
}else{
  src =nextgettok;
} does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
if(*delims){
  nextgettok = src;
}else{
  src =nextgettok;
}
```

does not make a sense.

It seems you mean

```
if ( src ) nextgettok = src;
```

This while loop

```
while(*src)
{
```

can invoke undefined behavior in the case when the first argument is equal to `NULL` and according to the description of the function the first argument may be equal to NULL.

Also such a call of `strchr` as in these if statements

```
if(strchr(src,*delims) == NULL)nxt = src;
```

and

```
if(strchr(src,*delims) != NULL)
```

also does not make sense because the string pointed to by `delims`  can contain more than one character.

Instead of the function `strchr` you should use the standard functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

So the function definition in whole does not make a sense.

Please reread the description of the function `strtok` at least in the internet.